# Setting a breakpoint at system call

Tags: linux, operating-systems

I want to modify my teamspeak server (linux), I'm particulary interested in the connection with clients (UDP), so I figured I need to set a breakpoint at the linux socket function to start reversing. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: For write: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235436/how-can-i-monitor-whats-being-put-into-the-standard-out-buffer-and-break-when-a

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `gdb` you can set a syscall breakpoint with `catch syscall`.

If this is in 32-bit x86 (IA-32), check the syscall number in `your_linux_source_dir/usr/include/asm/unistd_32.h`. There is no syscall called `socket` in 32-bit x86, do you mean `socketcall`? Its number is 102.

If this is in x86-64 (AMD64), check the syscall number in `your_linux_kernel_source_dir/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h`. The syscall called `socket` is 41.

Then run the executable in `gdb`:

```
$ gdb myexecutable
```

And set the syscall breakpoint (41 is the `socket` syscall number in x86-64, change to appropriate syscall number for you):

```
(gdb) catch syscall 41
```

And then run the program:

```
(gdb) r
```

Using the name of syscall (such as `socket`) instead of the number (eg. `41`) may also work, depending on your configuration.

Comment: I have no idea when this was added. But now you can use the syscall name instead of its number. So, just `catch syscall socket`.